# C# call an API through proxy using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, api, httpwebrequest

I want to make an API call (outside my organization domain) in my existing application, the network team has told me to set up a proxy config - only then it'd have the ability to go to the internet.
Dev has the ability to go to the internet without referencing the proxy setup.

In my dev environment, it is working fine since the ports are open, how to configure a proxy for UAT environment so that it can hit the new target on the internet?
proxy IP is given by the network team for Non-prod: 12.XXX.XXX.0 Port 80

and also how to check:

- if the above proxy is alive?
- once it is configured how to check if the request is going through the
  proxy because I just have dev server access where all ports are open,
  how would I check if it is configured correctly so that once deployed
  on UAT it works fine?

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpWebRequest` has a proxy property:

```
var myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
myWebRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy("host", 80);

try 
{
    var response = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
    //...
} 
catch (WebException e)
{
    // handling issues
}
```

If a request fails, an exception will be thrown that you can handle in `catch` block.

Comment: if it doesn't catch an exception, you meant it is passing through the proxy goes to internet and hitting the API ?